# How to create a list of Columns from a list of Strings

Tags: apache-spark

I want to create a list of columns from a arraylist of strings, how to achieve that in JAVA/SPARK ?

I try :

```
ArrayList<Column> cols = new ArrayList<Column>(listOfStrings);
```

But not working,
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do use.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;

List<Column> collect = Arrays.stream(listOfStrings)
    .map(functions::col).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Update:

```
List<Column> arrayList = listOfStrings.stream()
            .map(functions::col).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: No in your example if i specify List<String> listOfStrings then it is not accepted as an argument of Arrays.stream

Comment: listOfStrings.toArray() even worsen the error

Comment: Alright, now is it possible to pass arrayList as a parameter for `Window.partitionBy(arrayList)`  ?

Comment: Yes you can pass list in varargs methods as `Window.partitionBy(arrayList.toArray(new Column[arrayList.size()]));`